# Nullpointer exception in doPost

Tags: java, servlets

I have de following Form:

```
        <form action="/AppStore/publish" method="post" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Do you have an Account already?</legend>
                <input type="radio" name="registred" value="yes"> Yes
                <input type="radio" name="registred" value="no"> No
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>About your App</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="AppDesc">Describe it:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="AppDesc" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label for="AppName">Name:</label></td> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="AppName" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>    
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

I pass this data to a Java Servlet, but every time I get a Nullpointer Exception at getParameter("AppDesc"), instead getParameter("AppName") works fine, what do I wrong?

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    RequestDispatcher dispetcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/publishForm.jsp");
    List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Validating form input...

    if(request.getParameter("AppName").toString().isEmpty())
    {
        errorMessages.add("Please type a valid Name for your App.");
    }

    if(request.getParameter("AppDesc").toString().isEmpty())
    {
        errorMessages.add("The Description of your App should contain at least 160 Characters.");
    }
```

Comment: `"AppDescr"` doesn't match with what you've there in Servlet and HTML code shown as far. Are you sure you're running the code you think you're running? By the way, expecting non-null parameters is a really bad design. You should **also** check first if it is not null. Further, the `toString()` call is entirely superfluous. It's `String` already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `request.getParameter("...").toString()`.

`request.getParameter()` already returns a string reference, so you don't actually need to call `toString()` to get the value as a string, but it will return a null reference if the parameter is missing - in which case calling `toString()` will throw an exception. You need to check whether the value is null or empty. For example:

```
String description = request.getParameter("AppDesc");
if (description == null || description.isEmpty())
...
```

Of course, there are libraries around to check for "null or empty" - for example, in [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) you could use:

```
if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(description))
```

Answer (score 1):

If `request.getParameter("AppDesc")` is `null`, then

`request.getParameter("AppDesc").toString().isEmpty()` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Why not change the condition to:

```
   if(request.getParameter("AppDesc") == null ||   
      request.getParameter("AppDesc").toString().isEmpty()))
   {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><input type="text" name="AppDescr" /></td>
```

You've named the actual field `AppDescr` (notice the trailing "r"), but you're calling `getParameter` for `AppDesc` (sans "r").

EDIT: Or not... you edited your post and fixed it.  Was this not the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It must be the case that `request.getParameter("AppDesc")` returns a null value, causing the chained `toString()` to generate a NullPointerException.

This parameter was never set; the name specified in the html was "AppDesr" (note the trailing 'r').

Answer (score 0):

Your question title says `doGet`, your code says `doPost`. The difference between those two might explain your problem. :-)